# How to remove google plus button from activity view controller?

Tags: ios, google-plus, uiactivityviewcontroller

If a user has installed Google plus, then he would be able to select the Google plus app using the more button and show the google plus icon on the activity view controller. Is there a way to remove the the google plus button?

I have added the following code but it still does not help:

```
avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[@"com.google.GooglePlus.ShareExtension"];
        //-- show the activity view controller
        [self presentViewController:avc
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough

Comment: Edited question. Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to know the activity type that the Google Plus extension is using. You can find this by adding:

```
[(UIActivityViewController *)controller setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
  NSLog(@"type: %@", activityType);
}];
```

Select the Google Plus action and share something; the console will log the type identifier for you.

Then you'll need to add it to your `excludedActivityTypes`.

```
((UIActivityViewController *)controller).excludedActivityTypes = @[@"<whatever the type was>"];
```

Comment: So then did you have success removing the Google Plus button?

Comment: So when you exclude the type and the Google Plus button is still there, what does your `NSLog` in the completion handler for your `UIActivityViewController` say the activity type is?